# Google sheets: updating values to multiple keys with one call

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

It seems I can only update one file with one key at a time: `service.spreadsheets().values().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=key,                                                           body=body).execute()`

are there any tricks to update multiple workbooks with one call using multiple keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer for "are there any tricks to update multiple workbooks with one call using multiple keys?"

Unfortunately, in the current stage, the answer is No. The endpoint of spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate is as follows.

```
POST https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values:batchUpdate
```

In this endpoint, one spreadsheetId is included. So unfortunately, this method can request to only one Spreadsheet by one API call. Of course, several updates can be run to one Spreadsheet using spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate by one API call.

For example, if [the batch requests like Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch) can be run, spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate could be used to several Spreadsheets by one API call. But in the current stage, such method cannot be used yet.

#### Workaround

If OP pays attention to the quotas of Sheets API, how about this workaround? In this workaround, Web Apps with Google Apps Script is used. When ["Spreadsheet services"](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/) of Google Apps Script is used, the quotas of Sheets API are not reduced even if it updates several Spreadsheets. The flow of this workaround is as follows.

1. Create a script that you want to do by Spreadsheet services of Google Apps Script.
2. Deploy the script as Web Apps.

   - At this time, you can also use the access token for accessing to Web Apps by setting of Web Apps.
3. Use the Web Apps using Python script like an API.

#### References:

- [spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate)
- [Spreadsheet services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/)
- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)

Comment: I'm more concerned with speed of update. I have many sheets, but alot of quota.

Comment: @jason I think that if you have enough quotas and you want to reduce the process cost, in the current stage, the method which requests spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate to each Spreadsheet is suitable. Furthermore, if each update can be independent on each Spreadsheet, for example, you can also request the API with asynchronous processing.

Comment: I'm just curious, have you tried using the REST API in a multithread? does that work? Or is there conflicts in credentials?

Comment: I'm using `Pool` from `multiprocessing` and it seems I'm hitting diminishing returns for speed improvement for the call at 6-8 processes. I'm getting a 3-4x speed benefit.

Comment: @jason Thank you for your additional information. Also in my environment, I could confirm that Sheets API can be used with the asynchronous processing. But I have never measured about the detail of process cost of Sheets API under the asynchronous processing yet. I apologize for this situation.